# How to WIC Encode a D2D bitmap to png

Tags: c#, wpf, encode, direct2d, wic

At the moment I'm programming a paint app in WPF C# and have a problem. I want to draw different shapes and save them as a png/bmp. So right now I'm decoding a bmp to a direct2d bitmap to draw on rendertarget. But my problem is that I don`t know how to save the D2DBitmap as a png because I can not find a encode function...

I am not allowed to use SharpDX so I hope someone can help me with this problem.

Or maybe somebody has another solution for drawing shapes and stuff but NOT in the xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed it by myself.

I created a surfaceRenderTarget that can be painted on and also is shown on Screen.

Then I created a WicBitmapRenderTarget with the same properties and this Rendertarget is easily saveable with a saveToFile method.

So I draw on the surfaceRenderTarget and push every operation to an operationstack and when I click the save button the programm draws the hole stack on the bitMapTarget and saves this.

This is my solution, maybe someone has a better.